# Rspec: Testing view and layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have an model which holds `keywords` and `description` metadata, which are rendered on `show` action, within `<head>` tag. I want to test that `<meta>` tags are being rendered on the page with appropriate content.

I can do a controller test easely (checking the rendered content), but since the test implies inspections of rendered content I assume that a `view` test is actually what would be a more suitable here.

The problem is that I need to render the template for `show` action with layout rendering turned on, since `<meta>` tags are rendered within the later.

So the questions are:

1. Am I right trying to do a view test here?
2. If so, how do I turn layout rendering on when testing views?

I'm using the latest available `rspec-rails` gem.

Comment: Just mine own opinion: that's overtesting. You can't specify each line of code, and you shouldn't. View specs looks like bad idea at all. You need to test behavior - not presence of element.

Comment: I agree, it's not the thing that is worth testing. It looks like testing rails itself - if I write `my_model.keywords` in the view I want to check if I really see the keywords. It's how rails works and it's already tested.